# What is the different between map.put and creating a new map?

Tags: java, hashmap, volatile

i'm reading the source code of sentinel, i find when the map need adding a entry, it create a new hashmap replacing the old rather than using map.put directly. like this:

```java
public class NodeSelectorSlot extends AbstractLinkedProcessorSlot<Object> {

    private volatile Map<String, DefaultNode> map = new HashMap<String, DefaultNode>(10);

    @Override
    public void entry(Context context, ResourceWrapper resourceWrapper, Object obj, int count, boolean prioritized, Object... args)
        throws Throwable {
      
        DefaultNode node = map.get(context.getName());
        if (node == null) {
            synchronized (this) {
                node = map.get(context.getName());
                if (node == null) {
                    node = new DefaultNode(resourceWrapper, null);
                    // create a new hashmap
                    HashMap<String, DefaultNode> cacheMap = new HashMap<String, DefaultNode>(map.size());
                    cacheMap.putAll(map);
                    cacheMap.put(context.getName(), node);
                    map = cacheMap;
                    ((DefaultNode) context.getLastNode()).addChild(node);
                }

            }
        }

        context.setCurNode(node);
        fireEntry(context, resourceWrapper, node, count, prioritized, args);
    }
...
}
```

what's the different between them?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between objects and references to objects? When you call `someMap.put()`, all references to the thing at `someMap` will see the modification. When you say `someMap = newMap(...)`, that only overwrites your local reference. It's the difference between updating someone's address in your phone, and going to their house and rearranging the furniture.

Comment: In this case I suspect there's also something going on with multithreading - map is private and this particular method is synchronized, so it seems unlikely that other references should be allowed to exist. That's hard to say for certain without seeing more of the surrounding code, tho.

Comment: To be clear: the question is "**why** does the code create a new map, add the key, and reassign the name (instead of just adding the key to the existing map)?" Or just what?

Answer (score 0):

The code you are looking is fetching a Node from the map, creating and adding a new `Node` if one is not present.

Clearly, this operation needs to be thread-safe.  The simple ways to implement this would be:

- Lock the map and perform `get` and `put` operations while holding the lock.
- Use a `ConcurrentHashMap` which has operations for doing this kind of thing atomically; e.g. `computeIfAbsent`.

The authors of this code have chosen a different approach.  They are using so-called Double Checked Locking (DCL) to avoid doing the initial `get` while holding a lock.  That is what this code does:

```
    DefaultNode node = map.get(context.getName());
    if (node == null) {
        synchronized (this) {
            node = map.get(context.getName());
            ...
```

The authors have decided that when they then need to add a new entry to the map they need to do it by replacing the entire map with a new one.  On the face of it, that *seems* unnecessary.  The map updates are being performed while holding the lock and the `volatile` adds a *happens before* that *seems* to ensure that the initial `map.get` call sees any recent writes to the HashMap.

But that reasoning is INCORRECT.  The problem is that there is a small time window between fetching the `map` reference and the `get` call completing.  During that time window, a simultaneous `put` operation may be updating the `HashMap` data structures.  This is harmful because those changes could cause the `get` to read stale data (because there is no *happens before* relationship from the `put` writes to the `get` reads).  Even worse, the `put` could trigger reconstruction of a hash chain or even an expansion of the hash array.  The resulting behavior is (at least) outside of the `HashMap` spec, since `HashMap` is not defined to be thread-safe.

The authors' solution is to create a new `HashMap` with the existing entries and the new one, then update `map` with a single assignment.  I haven't done a formal analysis, but I think that this approach is thread-safe.

---

In short, the reason that the code creates a new `HashMap` is to make the DCL approach thread-safe.

And if you ignore the thread-safety aspect, this approach is functionality equivalent to a simple `put`.

Finally, we need to consider whether the authors' approach is going to give optimal performance.  The answer will depend on whether the number of cache entries stabilizes, and whether it is relatively small.  One observation is that the cost of adding `N` entries to the cache is `O(N^2)` !!  (Assuming that entries are never removed, as appears to be the case.)

Answer (score 0):

It is so-called [*copy-on-write*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write), which is intended to ensure thread-safe. When read operations are a lot more than write operations, it is more efficient than mechanisms like `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Ref: https://github.com/alibaba/Sentinel/issues/1733